# How to calc with operations in variable

Tags: php

is there a way in PHP to calc if the operations are in variables as strings? Like this:

```
<?php
    $number1=5;
    $number2=10;
    $operations="+";

    $result = $number1 . $operations . $number2;
?>
```

Comment: I get it, this is just an example, but still... `number1=5` -> `$number1=5;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the code you've given is a pseudo-code...

Given you have a limited set of operations that can be used, you can use switch case.

Using `eval()` can be a security issue if you are using user input for it...

A switch case example would be:

```
<?php

$operations = [
    '+' => "add",
    '-' => "subtract"
];

// The numbers
$n1 = 6;
$n2 = 3;
// Your operation
$op = "+";

switch($operations[$op]) {
    case "add":
        // add the nos
        echo $n1 + $n2;
        break;
    case "subtract":
        // subtract the nos
        echo $n1 - $n2;
        break;
    default:
        // we can't handle other operators
        throw new RuntimeException();
        break;
}
```

[In action](https://3v4l.org/qaSDY)

Comment: yeah I did it like this before but I work with a user input and i dont want to create to many switch cases or ifs

Comment: yeah... so if you are processing user input, you SHOULD NEVER use eval...

Comment: @DrSheldonTrooper don't use eval() when processing user input. Use a switch instead. Here an explanation about eval()  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Use `eval()`.

> Note: Avoid eval() It is not safe. Its Potential unsafe.

```
<?php

$number1=5;
$number2=10;
$operations="+";

$result= $number1.$operations.$number2;

echo eval("echo $result;");
```

**Output**

```
15
```

**Demo: [Click Here](https://eval.in/825011)**

Comment: ty, didn't knew about eval

Comment: eval() is not safe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php

Comment: Yes but as per questioner requirement I am helping. @Companjo

Comment: @RJParikh i understand, but it's better to inform him about the security risks too. Beside that, a switch is a better and safe alternative.

Comment: Ok, I forgot it. I have added note. @Companjo